# Create own (custom) modifier in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

**How can I make my custom modifiers in vuejs and how can I use them?**

- any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can create modifiers **only for your own custom directives**.

Vuejs doesn't allow to add additional modifiers to core directives like `v-model`, `v-on` etc.

Example with a custom directive:

```html
<div v-my-directive.uppercase="myVar" />
```

```js
const myDirective = {
  created(el, binding, vnode, prevVnode) {
    if(binding.modifiers.uppercase) {
      // Do whatever
    }
  },
}
```

Sources:

- Vuejs documentation: [Custom directives](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/custom-directives.html#directive-hooks)
- Vuejs issue [#3666](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3666): Add custom v-model modifier

Comment: in script use it like 
  '  directives: {
    myDirective,
  },

but its give error 

`No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type '{ created(el: HTMLElement, binding: any): void; }' is not assignable to type 'DirectiveFunction | DirectiveOptions'.
      Type '{ created(el: HTMLElement, binding: any): void; }' has no properties in common with type 'DirectiveOptions'.Vetur(2769)`